# Preparing the dataset and generating a co-occurrence matrix in python

Tags: python, json

I am working with Json files where i want to extract values and create co-occurrence matrix. These are users profiles each with two or more jobs titles. I want to extract these jobs titles and create a co-occurrence matrix.
[screenshot of Json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9et8z.png)
This is my code to extract the job title and the profile id to keep track of each profile. But am sure I need to group by the profile id and don't know how to go about it from here.

I will be grateful if someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

path = r"C:\Users\31685\Desktop\profiles\proc_profiles"
[My code to extract job titles and profile id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vB6d.png)